# PHP & SQL Server Error Handling?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP page which executes and inserts 3 different queries in a SQL Server database.

What is the best way to perform error handling with this?

Basically, I only want to execute them in series, so if the first one fails then DO NOT continue and basically put an error back to the client.

I have currently stored them in variables like

```
$sql_1 = "insert into ..."
```

and

```
$sql_2 = "insert into ..."
```

Then I was using if statements which were doing the calling of the variable but it just seems very messy.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccommend that you do all queries in a stored procedure, which you then call from your PHP page, the stored procedure can then return an error if something fails.
A very basic excample of stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 Insert ....

 delete....
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
SELECT 'Transaction failed'
END CATCH
```

Comment: Very good point... Yes I will be using Stored Proc's but during early development I was doing some hard coded SQL (ewww) just to get me off the ground and then turn into SP's. I'll defanately go down that path, I guess I can then rollback transactions in the SP as suggested

Comment: There might be some work involving passing all the data needed for all the inserts in one go.

Comment: True, but there is no information on how many or what kind of fields he would be passing so I left it out @hidden_4003

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use transactions? In case any of the queries fails, you execute rollback and post error to the client.

I use the following, query is just a wrapper around mssql_query + some additional logic with ERROR_MESSAGE() to get more informative error messages.

You might want to use PDO, i got this from an old project, works on MSSQL 2008.

```
function StartTransaction() {
    $sql = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ";       
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

    $sql = "set implicit_transactions on;";
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

}
function RollbackTransaction() {
    $sql = "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN";
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

    $sql = "set implicit_transactions off;";
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

    $sql = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED";       
    $res = $this->Query($sql);
}
function CommitTransaction() {
    $sql = "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN";
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

    $sql = "set implicit_transactions off;";
    $res = $this->Query($sql);

    $sql = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED";       
    $res = $this->Query($sql);
}
```

Comment: really? do you have an example? That would be just what I need! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a `exit ([ string $status ] );` this would stop your script straight away and you could display an error or change the header location to an error page.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

other wise use a series of if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Php has Try and Catch syntax for effective error handling. The following links might be of interest.

[PHP Try and Catch for SQL Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918624/php-try-and-catch-for-sql-insert)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php