# How to catch sql exceptions in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I am writing rest apis in php, but the errors are thrown when there are some null values are inserted in the api.It shows the sql query into the response page, how do I stop it from being displayed, what is the best exception handling in this case.I am bit new to php, so any help is appreciated.
Below is the sample code I write to query.

```
  $limit = " LIMIT ".$post_data['offset'].",".$post_data['limit'];
    $sql = "SELECT record_id from ";
    $shareResult= $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    if(empty($shareResult[0]['record_id']) || $shareResult[0]['record_id'] != 0){
        $query="SELECT *";

        $result= $this->db->query($query);
        if($result->num_rows()>0){
            $res1=$this->db->query($qry)->result_array();
            $res[0]=$res1[0];
            $res[1]=$result->result_array();
            return $res;
        }
    }else if($shareResult[0]['record_id'] === 0){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mysqli error in different environments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments)

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1918628/4841755. It might be helpfull.

Comment: Ref this - http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. Basically, you've to write your code like this - ```try { /* Place your code */ } catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; }```

Comment: It depends on the MySQL api you use in php to connect to MySQL. SO has dozens of question for each of them already.

Comment: I am using $this->db->query("Select *") to query the database.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I tried that way but it did not work

Comment: Share your code in your question.

Comment: error_reporting(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about Codeigniters default debug option you should take a closer look @your db config

Something like that should appear

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

Take a look at `db_debug` and set it to `false`.